# Using a Regex Back-reference In a Repetition Construct ({N})

Tags: regex

I need to match a string that is prefixed with an acceptable length for that string.

For example, `{3}abc` would match, because the `abc` part is `3` characters long. `{3}abcd` would fail because `abcd` is *not* `3` characters long.

I would use `^\{(\d+)\}.{\1}$` (capture a number `N` inside curly braces, then any character `N` times) but it appears that the value in the repetition construct has to be a number (or at least, it won’t accept a backreference).

For example, in JavaScript this returns true:

`/^\{(\d+)\}.{3}$/.test("{3}abc")`

While this returns false:

`/^\{(\d+)\}.{\1}$/.test("{3}abc")`

Is this possible to do in a single regex, or would I need to resort to splitting it into two stages like:

`/^\{(\d+)\}/.test("{3}abc") && RegExp("^\\{" + RegExp.$1 + "\\}.{" + RegExp.$1 + "}$").test("{3}abc")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regular expressions can't calculate, so you can't do this with a regex only.

You could match the string to `/^\{(\d+)\}(.*)$/`, then check whether `len($2)==int($1)`.

In Python, for example:

```
>>> import re
>>> t1 = "{3}abc"
>>> t2 = "{3}abcd"
>>> r = re.compile(r"^\{(\d+)\}(.*)$")
>>> m1 = r.match(t1)
>>> m2 = r.match(t2)
>>> len(m1.group(2)) == int(m1.group(1))
True
>>> len(m2.group(2)) == int(m2.group(1))
False
```

Comment: Ah, I figured as much. Thanks for confirming my suspicions.